# How can I save an entity without a key? Or with an auto increment id?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to save an entity using:

```
import requests

from google.cloud import datastore

def saveData(x):
    client = datastore.Client()
    entity = datastore.Entity()
    entity.update({'request': x})
    client.put(entity)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #obj = lambda: None
    #obj.data = lambda: "abcxyz"
    #processRequest(obj)
    saveData([123])
```

But get an error of: `ValueError: Entity must have a key`

How can I save this without a key?

According to 
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/471
it should be possible?

As well as: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys (but here it is using a class?)

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

from google.cloud import datastore

def saveData(x):
    client = datastore.Client()
    key = client.key('EntityKind')
    entity = datastore.Entity(key)
    entity.update({'request': x})
    client.put(entity)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #obj = lambda: None
    #obj.data = lambda: "abcxyz"
    #processRequest(obj)
    saveData([123])
```

Comment: As you alluded to in your answer, all datastore entities need to have a Kind, and the Kind is encoded as part of the key.